# advanced plotting (legend manipulation) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

I want to add a legend to my plot so that it look as in the picture (reduce the length of the line and suppress unnecessary spaces)

[image]

```
x = randn(6,20);

figure(2)
hax = gca;

plot(x(1,:),'--k','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(2,:),'b','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(3,:),'g','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(4,:),'r','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(5,:),'c','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(6,:),':r','linewidth',1.5);


ylabel('states','fontsize',14); xlabel('time(s)','fontsize',14);
legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
legendshrink(0.8,[]);
%Fig_legend = legend('Taylor','Euler','LLscheme','LLscheme1');
%set(Fig_legend,'FontSize',7)

grid(hax,'on')
axis(hax,'tight')
set(hax,'box','on','Layer','top');
set(hax,'tickdir','out')
```

is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported in the MatLab [online documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-colorbars-and-legends-not-valid-axes-handles.html) *Starting in R2014b, colorbars and legends are no longer axes objects*.

This limits the possibilites to work on the `legend` in order to achieve your target.

A possible solution could be to create a your own *axes based* legend following these steps:

- create the legend calling the `legend` function with the following syntax `[lgd,icons,plots,txt] = legend(___)` (notice, this syntax is *not recommended* nevertheless, we are going to delete the legend in the next steps, so it will not be a problem)
- get the position of the legend
- identify the number of items in the legend

  - for each line in the graph there are three items in the legend (the `line`, the `marker` and the `text`)
  - in the case of six line in a graph the legend handle will contains `18` objects in the following order:

    - 6 x handles to `text`
    - for each of the 6 lines

      - 1 handle to the line
      - 1 handle to the marker
- get the data of the items in the legend:

  - line data: `XData`, `YData`, `Color`, 'LineStyle`
  - text data: `string`, `position`
- delete the original legend
- add an `axes` to the figure with position and size equal to the original legend
- plot on this axes the lines that will represent the legend (you've got the data on the previous steps)
- to shrink the lines, just reduce reduce the value of the second element of `XData`
- add the legend text correspinding to the line (with the [text](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function. Since in the previous step you've recuced the lengt of the lines you've to move on the left the text
- reduce the size of the `axes`:

  - you can use the `Extent` property of the `text` items to identify the length of the longer one
  - then add to it the length of the corresponding line
- update the `axes` position (its `width`) with the value caomputed in the above step

This is a possible implementation (based on you code):

```
x = randn(6,20);

figure(2)
hax = gca;

plot(x(1,:),'--k','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(2,:),'b','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(3,:),'g','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(4,:),'r','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(5,:),'c','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(6,:),':r','linewidth',1.5);


ylabel('states','fontsize',14); xlabel('time(s)','fontsize',10);
%legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
%
% New call "legend"
%
[leg_h,leg_item_h,~,~]=legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
%
% legendshrink(0.8,[]);
%Fig_legend = legend('Taylor','Euler','LLscheme','LLscheme1');
%set(Fig_legend,'FontSize',7)

grid(hax,'on')
% axis(hax,'tight')
set(hax,'box','on','Layer','top');
set(hax,'tickdir','out')

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% GENERATION OF THE LEGEND %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define a scale factor fot the lines
line_scale_factor=1.4;
% Define a scale factor fot the lines
text_scale_factor=1.35;
% Get the "Position" of the legend
orig_leg_pos=get(leg_h,'position')
% Get the number on objects in the legend
n_obj=length(leg_item_h);
% Extract the "Line" object
line_obj=leg_item_h(n_obj/3+1:2:n_obj);
% Get the "LineStyle" of each "Line" in the legend
l_style=get(line_obj,'LineStyle')
% Get the "Color" of each "Line" in the legend
l_col=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'color'))
% Get the "XData" and "YData" of the "Lines" in the legend
leg_x_data=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'xdata'))
leg_y_data=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'ydata'))
% Get the handle of the "Text" of the items in the legend
leg_t=leg_item_h(1:n_obj/3)
% Get the "Text" of the items in the legend
str=get(leg_t,'string')
% Get the "Position" of each "Text" item in the legend
tx=cell2mat(get(leg_t,'position'))
% Delete the original legend
delete(leg_h)
% Create an axes with the same position and size of the original legend
ax=axes('position',orig_leg_pos,'xlim',[0 1],'ylim',[0 1], ...
   'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'box','on')
hold on
% Add the legend items to the axes
for i=1:n_obj/3
   % Add the lines with the original settings (color, style, ...)
   plot([leg_x_data(i,1) leg_x_data(i,2)/line_scale_factor],leg_y_data(i,:),'color',l_col(i,:), ...
                          'linestyle',l_style{i}, ...
                          'linewidth',1.4)
   % Add the text
   th(i,:)=text(leg_x_data(i,2)/text_scale_factor,tx(i,2),0,str{i},'fontsize',9, ...
           'unit','normalized')
end
% Get the maximun extent of the lagend "Text"
tx_max_ext=max(reshape([th(:).Extent],4,6)');
% Evaluate the axis scaling factor
tx_r_1=tx_max_ext(3)+leg_x_data(i,2)/line_scale_factor
% Get the axes position
axp=ax.Position
% Resize the axes width
ax.Position=[axp(1) axp(2) axp(3)*tx_r_1 axp(4)]
```

[image]

Comment: @ il_raffa, but when I try to show the figure in the full screen every thing I did it disappears.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to MatLab until next Saturday. I'll check and I'll let you know.