# Add flexible legend in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, legend-properties

I am trying to add a flexible legend (reduce the length of the line and suppress the unnecessary space between the line and the text) to my figure, I used the steps from another post : [advanced plotting (legend manipulation) in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740907/advanced-plotting-legend-manipulation-in-matlab[1]), the code it work fine but when I try to show the figure in the full screen after the legend modification, Everything I have done is meaningless.

```
x = randn(6,20);

figure(2)
hax = gca;

plot(x(1,:),'--k','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(2,:),'b','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(3,:),'g','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(4,:),'r','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(5,:),'c','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(6,:),':r','linewidth',1.5);


ylabel('states','fontsize',14); xlabel('time(s)','fontsize',10);
%legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
%
% New call "legend"
%
[leg_h,leg_item_h,~,~]=legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
%
% legendshrink(0.8,[]);
%Fig_legend = legend('Taylor','Euler','LLscheme','LLscheme1');
%set(Fig_legend,'FontSize',7)

grid(hax,'on')
% axis(hax,'tight')
set(hax,'box','on','Layer','top');
set(hax,'tickdir','out')

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% GENERATION OF THE LEGEND %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define a scale factor fot the lines
line_scale_factor=1.4;
% Define a scale factor fot the lines
text_scale_factor=1.35;
% Get the "Position" of the legend
orig_leg_pos=get(leg_h,'position')
% Get the number on objects in the legend
n_obj=length(leg_item_h);
% Extract the "Line" object
line_obj=leg_item_h(n_obj/3+1:2:n_obj);
% Get the "LineStyle" of each "Line" in the legend
l_style=get(line_obj,'LineStyle')
% Get the "Color" of each "Line" in the legend
l_col=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'color'))
% Get the "XData" and "YData" of the "Lines" in the legend
leg_x_data=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'xdata'))
leg_y_data=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'ydata'))
% Get the handle of the "Text" of the items in the legend
leg_t=leg_item_h(1:n_obj/3)
% Get the "Text" of the items in the legend
str=get(leg_t,'string')
% Get the "Position" of each "Text" item in the legend
tx=cell2mat(get(leg_t,'position'))
% Delete the original legend
delete(leg_h)
% Create an axes with the same position and size of the original legend
ax=axes('position',orig_leg_pos,'xlim',[0 1],'ylim',[0 1], ...
   'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'box','on')
hold on
% Add the legend items to the axes
for i=1:n_obj/3
   % Add the lines with the original settings (color, style, ...)
   plot([leg_x_data(i,1) leg_x_data(i,2)/line_scale_factor],leg_y_data(i,:),'color',l_col(i,:), ...
                          'linestyle',l_style{i}, ...
                          'linewidth',1.4)
   % Add the text
   th(i,:)=text(leg_x_data(i,2)/text_scale_factor,tx(i,2),0,str{i},'fontsize',9, ...
           'unit','normalized')
end
% Get the maximun extent of the lagend "Text"
tx_max_ext=max(reshape([th(:).Extent],4,6)');
% Evaluate the axis scaling factor
tx_r_1=tx_max_ext(3)+leg_x_data(i,2)/line_scale_factor
% Get the axes position
axp=ax.Position
% Resize the axes width
ax.Position=[axp(1) axp(2) axp(3)*tx_r_1 axp(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by moving the section of the above code that create the "new legend" into a `ResizeFcn` of the `figure`.

This allow adequating the size of the axes based legend each time the size of the figure changes.

To do so, you have to modify your code this way:

1) assign a `tag` to the figure, This will be used in the `ResizeFcn` to access to the figure:

```
cf=figure('tag','res_leg')
```

2) use [guidata](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) to store the original `legend` handles into the `figure` object

```
% Set in the FIGURE GUIDATA the legend handles
my_guidata=guidata(cf)
my_guidata.leg_h=leg_h;
my_guidata.leg_item_h=leg_item_h
% Store the GUIDATA data
guidata(cf,my_guidata)
```

3) Assign the `ResizeFcn` to the `figure`

```
set(cf,'ResizeFcn',['doResizeFcn(''' get(gcf,'tag') ''')'])
```

4) Define the `ResizeFcn`

just move the code you have now in the section in the section *% GENERATION OF THE LEGEND %* in a `function` named as the `ResizeFcn` (in this case `doResizeFcn`)

Make the following update to the above mentioned code (in the order they are in in the code):

4.1) Get the handle of the `figure`

4.2) Retrie the `figure` data using `guidata`

4.3) Check if the figure already contains the `axes` used in place of the legend; if so, delete it

4.4) Retrie the original legend data using `guidata`

4.5) Store in the `figure` guidata the handle of the `axes` created to replace the original legend

4.6) Store the figure's guidata

In the following the whole updated code - the above described steps are marked in the code as

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.1 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

**Original code for the plotting**

```
x = randn(6,20);
%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 1 %
%%%%%%%%%%
% Create the FIGURE and assign a TAG to it (to be used by FINDOBJ)
cf=figure('tag','res_leg')

hax = gca;

plot(x(1,:),'--k','linewidth',1.5);
hold on;
plot(x(2,:),'b','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(3,:),'g','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(4,:),'r','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(5,:),'c','linewidth',1.5);
% hold on;
plot(x(6,:),':r','linewidth',1.5);


ylabel('states','fontsize',14); xlabel('time(s)','fontsize',10);
%legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
%
% New call "legend"
%
[leg_h,leg_item_h,~,~]=legend('True','SCKS(h1)','SCKS(h2)','SCKS(h3)','SCKS(h4)','DEM',14);
%
% legendshrink(0.8,[]);
%Fig_legend = legend('Taylor','Euler','LLscheme','LLscheme1');
%set(Fig_legend,'FontSize',7)

grid(hax,'on')
% axis(hax,'tight')
set(hax,'box','on','Layer','top');
set(hax,'tickdir','out')

%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 2 %
%%%%%%%%%%
% Set in the FIGURE GUIDATA the legend handles
my_guidata=guidata(cf)
my_guidata.leg_h=leg_h;
my_guidata.leg_item_h=leg_item_h
% Store the GUIDATA data
%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 3 %
%%%%%%%%%%
guidata(cf,my_guidata)
%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4 %
%%%%%%%%%%
% Assign a RESIZE function the the figure
set(cf,'ResizeFcn',['doResizeFcn(''' get(gcf,'tag') ''')'])
```

**Figure's ResizeFnc**

```
function doResizeFcn(str)
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.1 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Get the handle of the calling FIGURE
curr_fig=findobj('tag',str);
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.2 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Retrieve the GUIDATA
my_guidata=guidata(curr_fig)
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.3 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Check if the RESIZE function has been already called
if(isfield(my_guidata,'ax'))
   % if so, delete the previously created axes (used in place of the
   % legend)
   delete(my_guidata.ax)
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.4 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Get the old legend handles to retrieve the original legend data
leg_h=my_guidata.leg_h;
leg_item_h=my_guidata.leg_item_h

line_scale_factor=1.4;
% Define a scale factor fot the lines
text_scale_factor=1.35;
% Get the "Position" of the legend
orig_leg_pos=get(leg_h,'position')
% Get the number on objects in the legend
n_obj=length(leg_item_h);
% Extract the "Line" object
line_obj=leg_item_h(n_obj/3+1:2:n_obj);
% Get the "LineStyle" of each "Line" in the legend
l_style=get(line_obj,'LineStyle')
% Get the "Color" of each "Line" in the legend
l_col=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'color'))
% Get the "XData" and "YData" of the "Lines" in the legend
leg_x_data=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'xdata'))
leg_y_data=cell2mat(get(line_obj,'ydata'))
% Get the handle of the "Text" of the items in the legend
leg_t=leg_item_h(1:n_obj/3)
% Get the "Text" of the items in the legend
str=get(leg_t,'string')
% Get the "Position" of each "Text" item in the legend
tx=cell2mat(get(leg_t,'position'))
% Delete the original legend
% % % delete(leg_h)
leg_h.Visible='off'
% Create an axes with the same position and size of the original legend
ax=axes('position',orig_leg_pos,'xlim',[0 1],'ylim',[0 1], ...
   'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'box','on')

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.5 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Store in the FIGURE GUIDATA the axes handle
my_guidata.ax=ax;
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEP 4.6 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Store the FIGURE GUIDATA
guidata(curr_fig,my_guidata)

hold on
% Add the legend items to the axes
for i=1:n_obj/3
   % Add the lines with the original settings (color, style, ...)
   plot([leg_x_data(i,1) leg_x_data(i,2)/line_scale_factor],leg_y_data(i,:),'color',l_col(i,:), ...
                          'linestyle',l_style{i}, ...
                          'linewidth',1.4)
   % Add the text
   th(i,:)=text(leg_x_data(i,2)/text_scale_factor,tx(i,2),0,str{i},'fontsize',9, ...
           'unit','normalized')
end
% Get the maximun extent of the lagend "Text"
tx_max_ext=max(reshape([th(:).Extent],4,6)');
% Evaluate the axis scaling factor
tx_r_1=tx_max_ext(3)+leg_x_data(i,2)/line_scale_factor
% Get the axes position
axp=ax.Position
% Resize the axes width
ax.Position=[axp(1) axp(2) axp(3)*tx_r_1 axp(4)]
end
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'